# Wordpress Site Misbehaving After Domain Assignment

Tags: php, wordpress, dns

I set up a WordPress site for a friend that worked as expected when being accessed strictly through the IP address. After my friend pointed her domain name to the IP address and changed either the WordPress Address or the Site Address in the Settings of the WordPress dashboard(she doesn't remember), the site looks like raw HTML and when trying to log in as the admin, a page is shown saying "[domain].wordpress.com does not exist".

I asked her to get her domain to stop pointing to the IP address. Now when I try going to the IP addpress and then using the log in link, I am redirected to a wordpress.com domain and asked to log in.

I am far out of my depth. What is happening to my friends WordPress site?

Answer (score 0):

The URL needs to be changed in many places. What I do when migrating site is:

1. Export your database to SQL file.
2. Open the SQL file.
3. search and replace the old URL to current like xyz.com to abc.com
4. save and reimport the same file again.

And it works as expected.